# Select2 in Vue.js is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jquery-select2

I want to use Select2 with Vue.js to display some selectable options, but however I implement it, there is always the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: select2 is not defined

at Object.select2 (external "select2":1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:766)
at fn (bootstrap:129)
at Module../src/jquery.js (jquery.js:3)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:766)
at fn (bootstrap:129)
at Module../src/main.js (main.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:766)
at fn (bootstrap:129)
at Object.0 (Home.vue?1405:1)
```

I installed the npm package with this command: npm install --save select2. I don’t know if this is the official package. I included the cdn link in the index.html and I added a require in a special file (jquery.js) which is directly included in main.js

jquery.js:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery
require('select2')
```

Select2.vue:

```
<script>
    import jQuery from 'jquery';
    let $ = jQuery;

    export default {
        name: 'select2',
        props: ['options', 'value'],

        mounted: function () {

            var vm = this

            $(this.$el).select2({
                    data: this.options,
                    tags: true
                }).on('change', function () {
                    vm.$emit('input', this.value)
                });
        },
        watch: {
            value: function (value) {
                // update value
                $(this.$el)
                    .val(value)
                    .trigger('change')
            },
            options: function (options) {
                // update options
                $(this.$el).empty().select2({data: options,tags: true})
            }
        },
        destroyed: function () {
           $(this.$el).off().select2('destroy')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's really not recommended to use jquery with vue. If you need a rich dropdown you can use for example [vuetify select](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects).

Comment: I know, but my boss sticks to Select2 ...

Answer (score 3):

I also recommend other [amazing Vue component Select2](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/).

But if you cannot convince your boss that you will get the model updated in the vue system easy and you hace to spend a lot of time to develop, here are some ideas to try:

Delete jquery.js, and change Select2.vue to add `require('select2')` to select2.vue:

```
<script>
  import jQuery from 'jquery';
  window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
  require('select2');
 ...
```

then, in your parent component use import with relative paths:

```
import Select2 from "../stangeComponents/Select2.vue";
```

I suppose you copy all from the [Wrapper Component Example from Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html) and everything should work...

Hope it helps :)